# Trigger something in post-receive only when new tag is added

Tags: git, githooks

I want to **do some action** in GIT's `post-receive` hook when **only new tag is pushed** to the repository. How to accomplish this?

Thanks

---

**SOLUTION (answer by Jan Krüger)**

New tag has `$oldrev` equalled zeroes. Removed tag has `$newrev` equalled zeroes. For both `$ref` value starts with `refs/tags/`.

```
#!/bin/sh
#

read oldrev newrev ref

if [[ "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" == $oldrev ]] && [[ $ref == refs\/tags\/* ]];
then
    echo "New tag added"
fi
```

Comment: Note that this should be `while read oldrev newref ref; do ... done` since I can, e.g., `git push origin branchA branchB tagC`, in which case the remark about my change that creates `tagC` is the *third* input line, not the *first* input line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `post-receive` hook receives information on stdin about all the refs (branches, tags, ...) that were updated in that operation. Each line has the following format, taken from the [`githooks` manpage](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks):

```
<old-value> SP <new-value> SP <ref-name> LF
```

So this would be an example of a new tag being created:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567 refs/tags/mytag
```

You simply need to read from stdin and check whether a line matches this format. Basically the first "word" is all zeroes and the third word starts with `refs/tags/`.