# post-receive is not being executed

Tags: bash, git, githooks, git-tag

I am working on post-receive hook and git tag and I found a sample post-receive from [Trigger something in post-receive only when new tag is added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55278195/trigger-something-in-post-receive-only-when-new-tag-is-added) .
However, when I create a tag
`git tag -a v0.0.1-test -m 'test tag1' and git push origin v0.0.1-test`

nothing happened. I was expecting the echo command to be triggered. Please help me to understand why it did not execute. (I already did chmod +x post-receive)

```
#!/bin/sh
#

read oldrev newrev ref

if [[ "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" == $oldrev ]] && [[ $ref == refs\/tags\/* ]];
then
    echo "New tag added"
fi
```

Comment: What evidence do you have that the hook is running at all?  `[[ refs/tags/test == refs/tags/* ]] && echo yes` prints `yes` for me.

Comment: `post-receive` is a hook installed in the remote repository. Have you installed it in the local repository? If so, `git push` in the local repository won't invoke it. If you only want to test the hook, you can try `git push . HEAD:refs/tags/foo`. But still, you need to install it in the remote repository for real use.

Comment: @ElpieKay I am pushing it from my local repository. How can you install it in remote? is github a remote repository?

Comment: @john316 If it's hosted in Github, I'm afraid you need to use Github's webhooks instead of githooks.

Comment: @ElpieKay what should i do to trigger it when I want to push from my local machine to github repo? I do not really know the difference between local and remote repo...

Comment: @john316 the repository on your local machine works as  the local repository and the repository on Github works as the remote repository. When you run `git push`, you are sending data from the local repository to the remote one. Github does not use githooks. Instead, like other hosting services such as Gitlab and Gerrit, it implements a set of its own hooks (https://developer.github.com/webhooks/). I'm not a heavy Github user, so I'm afraid I can't give you any advice on its webhooks. Google could help.

Comment: @ElpieKay You've helped tremendously. Thanks for your help!!